# How can I convert JSON data to Protein Data Bank (PDB) using Python script?

Tags: python, json

I would like to convert my JSON data to Protein Data Bank (PDB) format using Python script. I was able to convert them to CSV, however I couldn't convert them to PDB-format. Any help to convert JSON data or CSV to Protein Data Bank (PDB) would be appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: http://biocomp.chem.uw.edu.pl/A3D/tutorial_txt  Check out this site too.

Comment: JSON and CSV are very generic data formats, you should provide an example of what you are trying to convert, and your best guess at how the end result should look like.

Protein Data Bank sounds like a domain-specific format. It will not be familiar to most people who know what JSON and CSV are.

Comment: Examples of PDB Format https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/tutorials/pdbintro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PDB Tools](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6343223/)

Otherwise, I don't think there is a python library to do this task. You will need to use an online api from a site like  https://convertio.co/xls-pdb/ . Their api is at https://developers.convertio.co/. I just saw that it doesn't have easy python access and only cli support. So in this case you will need to run api request through a subprocess.

Edit:

Reading:
[Pandas Multiindexed DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)

The csv can be loaded into pandas and converted to a tab separated table. I 'm talking about it after seeing this [Link 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank_(file_format)#Example)  [Link 2](http://files.rcsb.org/view/1mbs.pdb).

```
df = pd.read_csv(...)
df.to_csv("myfile.pdb" , sep="\t")
```

might work. If this fails, then `df.to_csv("myfile.csv" , sep="\t")` and renaming from `.csv` to `.pdb` might work.

Look at this biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec177. Otherwise the only option left is to manually make all those indents in a notepad file(can be done programatically) and then save it as .pdb

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try the online converter. But it didn't work. The output didn't have a correct format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution. However still I don't get the pdb- standard format. That is the code that I used to covert json to csv: `import pandas df= pandas.read_json("json_file.json") df.to_csv("csv_file.csv")`

Comment: https://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation  Can you look here if these people might have something for you?

Comment: I think it w'd be a good idea to ask those guys for help since your problem is related to that domain. Join their mailing list or post a feature request on github.

Comment: Look at this  http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec177. Otherwise the only option left is to manually make all those indents in a notepad file(can be done programatically) and then save it as .pdb

Comment: Yes, That is what I was thinking too. Thanks.

Comment: I think you got an idea for a pypi project. It will help others who are seeking help.You can ask for help from me via the chat since  I 'm interested in getting involved in open source.